# batch file with logon type criteria

Tags: powershell, batch-file, event-viewer, winlogon

Im hoping i could have a push in the right direction for an issue I'm having. Im not even sure it is possible.

Idea:

Id like to have a batch file that runs on logon to check the logon type that is shown in the event viewer.

The ultimate goal is to allow logon with a keyboard at the station - password entered > logon type checked from event viewer (logon type 2)> if logon type 2 check to see if a USB with a certain serial is connected> if yes allow >if no lock PC right away.

issues:

I have no idea and have not found a way to get the logon type from the event viewer, It will only have to check the newest record.

i have the file that checks for the serial and if not EQU locks PC. its the event viewer I'm not sure on.

Im looking for this in a batch file. or Powershell (if this can be run at logon, i have never used this before)

Thanks for any and all help!!

Comment: I believe the answer to your question has already been covered here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393437/get-winevent-obtain-interactive-logon-messages-only
You can filter out the logon type using the Get-WinEvent command in powershell; or the Get-Eventlog command for older operating systems.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! wasn't sure what to search for with powershell.
I also found you could set a trigger with a batch file based on an event with extra criteria. so event ID 4624 AND logon type **

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get-WinEvent Obtain Interactive Logon Messages Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393437/get-winevent-obtain-interactive-logon-messages-only)