# Get-WinEvent filter by logontype 2 OR logontype 3

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

I came accross this [Get-WinEvent Obtain Interactive Logon Messages Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393437/get-winevent-obtain-interactive-logon-messages-only) and tried to play around with `OR` in the same case:

```
 Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="c:\test.evtx"; id=4624;} | Where-Object {$_.properties[8].value -eq 2} OR {$_.properties[8].value -eq 3}
```

and I wonder that this is not working?

and what happens if I have two different eventid's with two different where clause, e.g. EventId `4624` and logontype `2` or logontype `3`
`OR`
eventid `1234` and hostname = `localhost`.

What I need to do is check only logontype:2 and logontype 3 and print Network-Details when logontype is 3 (remote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` is not valid in PowerShell... You probably mean `-or`!

In which case your code ends up looking like this:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="c:\test.evtx"; id=4624;} |
    Where-Object {$_.properties[8].value -eq 2 -OR $_.properties[8].value -eq 3}
```

As an addition, I often find the `-in` operator to be clearer in this kind of scenario

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path="c:\test.evtx"; id=4624;} |
    Where-Object {$_.properties[8].value -in 2, 3}
```